# IDENT_CURRENT equivalent for current session

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get the last inserted row in a specific table for strictly the current session.  I can't use `@@IDENTITY` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` as they will return the last inserted identity for ANY table.  The problem with `IDENT_CURRENT` is that it will return the last inserted identity of a record for a specific table but for ANY session.  This is a problem for me because the `INSERT` is called by multiple sessions, and I specifically need the identity of the last inserted record for my specific session.

Any pointers how to accomplish this?

ps. the `INSERT` statement is not inside a SPROC, so SPROC solutions are not viable.

Thanks

Comment: In what situation does SCOPE_IDENTITY() not work? Can you demonstrate with an example? IDENT_CURRENT is not the way to do this.

Comment: What exactly needs the ID?  Could you elaborate a little on the architecture you're working with? Are you trying to capture the ID value inserted into a table other than the one that's referenced in your query?

Comment: As I said, SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the identity of the last record inserted for ANY table....................

Comment: Only any identity created within YOUR scope. Again, please point out where this *doesn't* work.

Comment: The identity is auto inserted, so I don't have access to it until after the insert.

Comment: @user577240: yes, of course - that's the way it works. And once it's inserted, you can access it using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` - you **still** haven't shown an example / scenario where `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns a **wrong value** (according to your logic)

Comment: There could be multiple insert statements executed within the same scope depending of different conditional tests is my problem, so i need to specify a table to make sure I get the right one?

Comment: No, you don't. If you have multiple conditional inserts, why not assign the value within the same conditional?

Comment: fair enough, would insert triggers on some tables mess up my scope_identity? If not that would work, although not as elegantly as I would have to assign scope_identities to vars after each insert call but it would solve my problem if triggers don't interfere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know it's not the answer you seem to want to hear, but the answer is to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. The problem you are thinking of (where it will be for *any* table) is why we use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`. Consider the case where you have a table with an `IDENTITY` column, and an insert trigger on that table that itself inserts into a table with an `IDENTITY` column.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Log(LogID INT IDENTITY(100,1), FooID INT);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo(FooID INT IDENTITY(1,1), name VARCHAR(32));
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Foo_Insert
ON dbo.Foo
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT dbo.Log(FooID) SELECT FooID FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Now, your situation is that you want a reliable way to retrieve the ID after an insert. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` gives you that, since it is restricted to *your scope*, while `@@IDENTITY` is not restricted to your scope (meaning it will grab the last `IDENTITY` issued, which happened in the triggers' scope, not your scope:

```
INSERT dbo.Foo(name) SELECT 'Bob';

SELECT
  @@IDENTITY,
  SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Results:

```
----  ----
100   1
```

Note that neither `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` nor `@@IDENTITY` should be used in the case where you insert multiple rows. The way to do this would be to use the `OUTPUT` clause. First let's drop the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER dbo.Foo_Insert;
```

Now let's test a multi-row insert:

```
  INSERT dbo.Foo(name) 
    OUTPUT inserted.FooID, inserted.name
    SELECT 'Frank' UNION ALL SELECT 'Jim';
```

Results:

```
FooID  name
-----  -----
2      Frank
3      Jim
```

If you have conditional inserts, there is no difference. Keeping the tables we have, let's try this code twice:

```
DECLARE @table SYSNAME;
SET @table = N'Log';

IF @table = N'Log'
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Log(FooID) SELECT 10;
END

IF @table = N'Foo'
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Foo(name) SELECT 'Tom';
END

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Result:

```
----
101
```

Let's try it again with `N'Foo'`:

```
DECLARE @table SYSNAME;
SET @table = N'Foo';

IF @table = N'Log'
BEGIN
INSERT dbo.Log(FooID) SELECT 10;
END

IF @table = N'Foo'
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Foo(name) SELECT 'Tom';
END

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Results:

```
----
4
```

If it's more complex than that (e.g. you may insert into more than one table), you can do something like:

```
IF <some conditional>
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.sometable ...
    SET @somevar = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
IF <some other conditional>
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.some_other_table ...
    SET @some_other_var = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

I'm not sure why you think this doesn't work, and I'm not sure why I have to go to this length to convince you that it does. Again, if you show an example where this doesn't work (or what "ANY table" you think might interfere), we might be able to comment. As it stands it sounds like your opinion of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is based on something you've heard about `@@IDENTITY`. These assumptions are quite easy to prove or disprove yourself.

As an aside, `IDENT_CURRENT` should not even be mentioned in this conversation. It is not safe to use for concurrent activity at all, and you should pretend that you've never heard of it as far as I'm concerned. You should also consider the same for `@@IDENTITY` - I can't think of a valid use for it unless you really do want to capture, from outside of the trigger, the `IDENTITY` generated inside a trigger.

Comment: To answer your question, you went into this length to convince me is because you're passionate and your a helpful kind person.  I'm sorry I made you do this to prove your solution.  Thank you and much appreciated.

Comment: @user577240: you're fortunate - Aaron is (a) really good at explaining stuff like this, (b) as you say: very passionate about his topics, and (c) just really really helpful.

Comment: ...even if sometimes I sound like the old man in your neighborhood yelling at the kids to get off his lawn. Thanks @marc_s. :-)