# Can one get all of the identities of a block insert of records?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Considering the following TSQL:

```
INSERT INTO Address(Street1, City, State, ZipCode)
SELECT Street1, City, StateCode, ZipCode
    FROM Contact
```

The Address has an identity column that is automatically set. Is there a way to get a list of the identities of Address records newly inserted?

I know there is @@IDENTITY, but that just returns the last identity.

Comment: I think that this would depend on why do you want those records. You could use the `OUTPUT` clause, or a trigger for getting those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the identity column is called AddressID, you can:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Address(Street1, ...)
OUTPUT inserted.AddressID
SELECT Street1, ...
  FROM dbo.Contact;
```

Or:

```
DECLARE @NewAddresses TABLE(AddressID INT);

INSERT INTO dbo.Address(Street1, ...)
OUTPUT inserted.AddressID INTO @NewAddresses
SELECT Street1, ...
  FROM dbo.Contact;
```

Keep in mind `@@IDENTITY` should *almost* never be used. Even when dealing with single-row inserts, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is much safer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284395/ident-current-equivalent-for-current-session/11284761#11284761) for more background.

Comment: One question.  Is there now a way I can update those identities into an existing table?

Comment: I don't know what "update...into" means. But yes, if you put them into the @NewAddresses table, you can use that table as a source of further queries (including updates).

Comment: What I am wanting to do, that no one seems to understand, is create new default records in one table for each record in another table.  In the example above, I'm wanting to take the address information out of the Contact information and create an offshoot of Contact called Address that is referenced by a Foreign key in Contact.  I'm not actually working with Contacts and Addresses but it is an analog of what I am doing that is easier to understand.

Comment: "that no one seems to understand"? That's a little unfair. All your question asks about is how "to get a list of the identities." If you have a different problem after getting the list of identities, create a question that asks the question you want to ask. This is like wanting to get to San Francisco, and you start by asking me if I know where your car keys are, expecting me to reply with turn-by-turn directions to San Francisco.

Comment: No, this was frustration from another question.  I started asking the question in piecemeal as a result.  I guess I'll have to do just that.

Comment: Here is my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350702/how-can-i-split-off-one-table-into-another-table-using-tsql-script