# How can I split off one table into another table using TSQL script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this code so far:

```
DECLARE @AddressIDS TABLE
(
    AddressID int
)

INSERT INTO Address(Street1, City, StateCode, ZipCode)
OUTPUT inserted.AddressID INTO @AddressIDS
SELECT Street1, City, StateCode, ZipCode
    FROM Contact
```

Now I need to put the IDs in the `@AddressIDS` back into the `AddressID` of the `Contact` table.

This better describes what I'm trying to do in TSQL:

[image]

Comment: Oops, I have my cardinalities backwards.  Ah, well.

Comment: I'm sorry, who is being self-important here? You're wasting others' time asking for help with the wrong question, and then dismissing answers because they don't fit the model you haven't told us about. Please grow up a little bit and understand that we're not your servants and we're not mind-readers.

Comment: I apologize.  You are right.  I'm very frustrated. I need go get away from this damned problem for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Street1 + City + StateCode + ZipCode is unique, or that multiple contacts can share the same AddressID, then you don't need to suss out the AddressID values in an intermediate step. You can just perform your insert into Address and then:

```
UPDATE c 
  SET AddressID = a.AddressID
  FROM dbo.Contact AS c
  INNER JOIN dbo.Address AS a
  ON c.Street1 = a.Street1
  AND c.City = a.City
  AND c.StateCode = a.StateCode 
  AND c.ZipCode = a.ZipCode;
```

Comment: Alas, you've found how my analog doesn't match my own situation.  Truth is there is nothing ultimately matching the proverbial `Address` and `Contact` tables in my situation.  So I cannot make a join.  The `Address` tables are all the same data, I just need to match them one at a time with the records in my `Contact` table.

Comment: I don't understand. You just did an insert into the address table with values in the contact table. How does it make sense that a join doesn't work? If you want honest and helpful answers then include some real tables and real sample data and real desired results. All this proverbial and analogous crap has to go, if the situation you're presenting has solutions that aren't actually applicable because the situation you're presenting is bullcrap and completely different from the problem you're actually trying to solve. If you want help, please ask for help correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reveal this particular situation. I have to be vague.  Oh well, I'll just have to figure it out myself.

Comment: Uh, you can't make up column names and sample data that actually reflect what you're trying to do? Ok, have fun.