# Using IDENT_CURRENT() of table during insert into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing table that has an identity column and a column that has a constraint to ensure that it matches the value in the identity column.
(I know that this is not a good design, but it is an old table that can not be changed at the moment)

I know that I can use the IDENT_CURRENT('mytable') as a value during the insert to put the newly created identity value into the other column (FakeID).

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FakeID)
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('MyTable')
```

I have seen that this has issues when inserting multiple records, but for this use I am only inserting a single record.

My question is how safe is this to use?
Mainly, is there a risk from inserts made under different sessions or in a different scope?
Also, does this behave as expected when the table is truncated?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you doing this work in a trigger?

Comment: @db_brad No, this is getting called as part of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() is going to be a safer bet here.  If someone inserts into the table before this part of your transaction runs, IDENT_CURRENT will grab the newly generated Id from the other transaction.

So I would declare a variable and set its value to SCOPE_IDENTITY(), something like this

```
DECLARE @Id INT
SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO MyTable (FakeID) 
SELECT @Id
```

Here are some posts on a similar issue:

http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/471026-ident_current-problem
[IDENT_CURRENT equivalent for current session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284395/ident-current-equivalent-for-current-session)

Comment: Thanks, but this misses what I'm looking for. I may not have made the question clear enough. This is a stand alone insert, and not part of a sequence. The SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the value from the previous insert which in my case either does not exist, or could be on a different table.